# PHP: Delete specific row in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to delete a row in my mysql database. Which row to be deleted is defined by a _GET tag. So if the page URL is deletePage.php?id=5 it wil delete the row with ID=5.

Here is my code so far:

```
<?php
 if (empty($_GET)) {echo "Error!";}
 else {
    include "../../includes/dke390d-ko.php";
    $pageID = $_GET['id'];;
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpasswd);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'DELETE FROM page
        WHERE id="$pageID"';

mysql_select_db($dbname);
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not delete data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Deleted data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
    header("Location: index.php");
    }
 ?>
```

My problem is that when i execute the code i am getting a error message saying: Could not delete data: Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'

I should probably put the ID in a session. But that'll come later.

Best regards!

Comment: So what's your question? Also, [please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). **You are also wide open to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)**

Comment: Is the column name `ID` or `id`?

Comment: @jcaron I upvoted your comment (earlier), OP's column was actually [`pageID`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453885/php-delete-specific-row-in-mysql#comment37842274_24453923)

Answer (score 3):

You have a variable in a string delimited by single quotes. As a result the variable is not interpolated. Swap your quotes to fix this:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM page
        WHERE id='$pageID'";
```

Like I said in my comments above, your code is obsolete and insecure. You should make fixing that a high priority.

Comment: [`Another "plug"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453885/php-delete-specific-row-in-mysql#comment37841875_24453936) ;-)

Comment: I chuckled when I clicked on the link and the page just reloaded. I wasn't expecting that. :)

Comment: Don't you just love the unexpected? Kinda like a suprise party where all your ex-GF's show up naked.

Comment: At the age we all are now, that's  party I would like to miss! lol

Comment: Tried, but i'm still getting an error saying: Could not delete data: Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well made, very nice and highly appropriate :-)

Comment: @user3420206 - show us your table - because if unknown id means the column id isn't even in the table

Comment: @user3420206 Also, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: @JohnConde I guess I should probably delete the comment I left under the other answer. lol

Comment: Added the error reporting. Now it's saying:Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\admin\executers\deletePage.php on line 7
Could not delete data: Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'

Link to image of table layout here [link](http://mariusweber.dk/sql.jpg)

Comment: There you go, you're using `id` where it should be `pageID` @user3420206 - `WHERE pageID='$pageID'";` also remove one of the `;` in `$pageID = $_GET['id'];;`

Comment: You're welcome. See? It pays to have error reporting on! ;-) Now, do accept John's answer, since the solution was found here. :) cheers @user3420206

Comment: I'm so good (lol) so, about that party....

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL family of PHP is deprecated and support thereof will disappear, if it hasn't yet. Please look into [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Now for the bigger issues, **never trust user input**. Your SQL is not safe against SQL injection, nor do you do any checks on the `$_GET` parameter. This is incredibly dangerous and reeks of disaster!

In PDO, there is a `prepare` statement that will sanitize input for you.

```
$sql = $dbh->prepare('DELETE FROM page  WHERE id=?');
$sql->execute(array($id));
```

The `execute` function takes an array and will replace any `?` in your code with parameters safely.

As mentioned above, I would also do a check on that `$_GET` parameter; keep in mind that a user can supply anything he wants, even if your form wouldn't allow it (the same applies for `$_POST`).

I would suggest something like:

```
if(!isset($_GET['id']) || !is_scalar($_GET['id']) || !is_numeric($_GET['id']))
   die('Invalid id!');
```

Assuming you'd want your ID to be numeric for the check with `is_numeric()`. Checking for `is_scalar()` helps prevent warnings that appear when the user visits something like `delete.php?id[]=t` which is really easy to do.

Comment: This isn't an answer. [`This is an answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24453923/)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Fixed, and fixed. I was a little eager to submit.

Comment: @ljacqu using GET requests to delete (or change) data reeks of disaster, OP should consider using POST requests.

Comment: I understand. It's usually best to include actual code to fix the OP's issue (*or hopefully fix*), instead of merely pointing out that the present method is open to SQL injection, noble as your suggestion was ;-) that wasn't my DV btw.

Comment: @VMai Sure, it's a little bit more difficult to send bogus `$_POST` data, but personally I would never consider `$_POST` any safer than `$_GET`. User input remains user input.

Comment: It's less a matter of security. GET requests should be cachable.

Comment: Sidenote: [`Solution is here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453885/php-delete-specific-row-in-mysql#comment37842402_24453923) (OP wasn't using error reporting also) cheers (*it pays to investigate*) ;-)